# Template parameter to a template - ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, templates

I found this example of another template passed as parameter to a template:

```
template<template<typename T> class AllocatePolicy>
struct Pool {
    void allocate(size_t n) {
        int *p = AllocatePolicy<int>::allocate(n);
    }
};


template<typename T> 
    struct allocator { static T * allocate(size_t n) { return 0; } };


int main()
{
    // pass the template "allocator" as argument. 

    Pool<allocator> test;



    return 0;
}
```

This seems perfectly reasonable to me but MSVC2012 compiler is complaining that "allocator: ambiguous symbol"

Is this a compiler-problem or is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you `abusing namespace std;` by any chance? Try renaming the allocator template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have an evil:

```
using namespace std;
```

Somewhere in your code, which makes your class template `allocator` clash with the `std::allocator` Standard allocator.

For instance, this code does not compile unless you comment the line containing the using directive:

```
#include <memory>

// Try commenting this!
using namespace std;

template<template<typename T> class AllocatePolicy>
struct Pool {
    void allocate(std::size_t n) {
        int *p = AllocatePolicy<int>::allocate(n);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct allocator { static T * allocate(std::size_t n) { return 0; } };

int main()
{
    Pool<allocator> test;
}
```